# Accept Jquery post only from my server (adress)

Tags: php, jquery

My site has a post request via jquery. I would not want anyone else to send this post a request from other sites and receive information.

*Is it possible to allow POST request via jquery + php only from MY site?*

Maybe somehow through `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`?

More: Some wise guy will make a copy of my POST request on his website and will receive all the information he needs. And I want the answer to come only when the POST request was sent directly from my site and ONLY.

**jquery post example:**

```
$("#get").click(function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
        'type': "POST",
        'dataType': "json",
        'url': "https://example.com/get.php",
        'data': { id: "123", text: "test text" },
        'success': function(response) {
            //var json = response;
            //alert(response);
        }
    });
});
```

**get.php example:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["id"]) && isset($_POST["text"])) {
        $id = $_POST["id"];
        $text = $_POST["text"];
        // If sent not from example.com
        // sql query and echo user information

        // else if sent from another domain ---> DIE ();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Did you tried `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` ?

Comment: Oh forgot this func) Thank you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways I can think of.

- Generate some kind of key and send it along with the request to check
  if it is valid. Or store it in session.
- In **.htaccess** limit POST requests only to your IP address.
- Compare `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` with your own domain.